# Rails : How to have different labels for multiple fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to rails and I am wondering how to have different labels or placeholders for multiple `fields_for`, my form works fine, but I want to change the way it's displayed.
Below is my form:

```
<%= f.fields_for :lodgedetails do |c| %>
  <%= c.text_field :contact, :placeholder => 'Contact1', :class => 'form-control lodge_form' %>
  <%= c.text_field :email, :placeholder => 'Email1', :class => 'form-control lodge_form' %>
<% end %>
```

and in the controller I have:

```
2.times {@lodge.lodgedetails.build }
```

Now the form is displayed as:

- contact1
- email1
- contact1
- email1

I want it to be:

- contact1
- contact2
- email1
- email2

How do I achieve the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the `each.with_index` to achieve this:

```
<% @lodge.lodgedetails.each.with_index do |lodge_detail, index| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :lodgedetails, lodge_detail do |c| %>
    <%= c.text_field :contact, :placeholder => "Contact#{index}", :class => 'form-control lodge_form' %>
    <%= c.text_field :email, :placeholder => "Email#{index}", :class => 'form-control lodge_form' %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The above will give you elements with placeholder containing the current index of the `lodgedetails` in the loop.

Comment: Thanks i tried it, how do i change the order?now its displaying as contact1,email1,contact1,email1 and i want it to be like contact1,contact2,email1,email2.

Comment: I got the solution,i had repeat the loop twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

```
<% @lodge.lodgedetails.each.with_index do |lodge_detail, ind| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :lodgedetails, lodge_detail do |c| %>
    <%= c.text_field :contact, :placeholder => "Contact#{ind}", :class => 'form-control lodge_form' %>
    <%= c.text_field :email, :placeholder => "Email#{ind}", :class => 'form-control lodge_form' %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

but when you try it the index value will start with zero so you have to increments by one or you can take a local instance for it and give the start value to it.

Comment: How do i change the order so its displayed as contact1,contact2,email1,email2 ?

Comment: At that time what it display to u ?